# Creating Cassandra column which takes only 0 or 1 as possible values

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I want to get the number of records with specific criteria (such as fraction of applications accepted using application id), which can be done by using 0 and 1 for rejected and accepted applications respectively, followed by using sum(application_acceptance)/count(*). However, I do not want the column to accept anything except 0 or 1.

I am looking for one of the following options, but not sure if Cassandra allows any of them:

1. Using boolean datatype with (0, 1) values instead of (true,false).
2. Using tinyint and restricting permissible values to (0,1).

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to restrict values? One way could be to use boolean as the type for column and create a UDF that would convert your boolean to int and run all selects using that UDF.

Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE b_table (
    key int PRIMARY KEY,
    bol1 boolean
)
```

UDF:

```
CREATE FUNCTION my_boolean(input boolean)
    RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
    RETURNS int
    LANGUAGE java
    AS 'return (input) ? 1 : 0;';
```

select: `select key, my_boolean(bol1) from b_table  ;`

Comment: @Kushagra Mittal has my answer been helpful? Did you find some other solution?